# "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'url"' by using matrix-js-sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, sdk

The error is:
`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'url'`
I my only code is:

```
import sdk from 'matrix-js-sdk';

const client = sdk.createClient("https://matrix.org");
client.login("m.login.password", {"user": "Jak2k", "password": localStorage.getItem("pass")}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.access_token);
});
```

Before that, I just installed [it](https://matrix.org/docs/guides/usage-of-the-matrix-js-sdk) with npm.(Maybe it's important, that I use react in the same package.)